# While re-sizing the Column in UltraWebGrid (asp.net) , column alignment has to be changed

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

While re-sizing the Column in UltraWebGrid (asp.net) , column alignment has to be changed...
All header names aligned to right from left side(ie. un-aligned format)

how to fix it??

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m3xz.png

Comment: Are you trying to change the alignment of the text within the header as the column is resized or do you have an issue with the column alignment becoming incorrect as you resize the columns?

Comment: see this image...http://i.stack.imgur.com/1m3xz.png

Comment: I am still not clear on what you are actually asking.  The image shows the grid in two different states one where the first field is sorted and one where both fields are sorted and I am not sure what the position of the header is in the second image relative to the first image because there is no data visible when the grid is sorted by the second column.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: 1st img is normal look...if i try to resize the column on it,then it look like 2nd img...

Comment: Are you saying that it sorts when you try to resize the column?  Or that the alignment of the headers is changing?  If the alignment of the headers is changing, do you have an example that still shows the data portion with the header?

Comment: if i change the alignment of the header,alignment of the all column's value has to be changed. i.e data in 2nd column come in 1st column(aft re-sizing) but header remain same!

Comment: I am still not following what your question is.  Can you post the relevant code, exact steps to reproduce the issue, results, and expected results?